# How to load Access file (.accdb) in Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, ms-access, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

as a new .NET developer I received a task to load access file (.accdb) in Azure Durable function.

I've written a pseudo code for console app

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
            myConn.Open();
            var dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, myConn);

            using (var dbDataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var dataTable = new DataTable();

                dataTable.Load(dbDataReader);

                using (var dataEnum = dataTable.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator())
                {
                    while (dataEnum.MoveNext() && dataEnum.Current != null)
                    {
                        var obj = dataEnum.Current.ItemArray;

                        foreach (var values in obj)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(values .ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And this code works with my .accdb file.

However, in Azure function, I can't import OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand and other classes that I need to read this file.

Does anybody have any idea how to do this?

Comment: MS Access is a hard requirement? Access is never the right choice as a backend. But have you tried importing [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb/) [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#using-nuget-packages)?

Comment: This package actually helped me. Thanks